# Reduce regions on projected (equal-area) data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reducers, memoryerror

I am working with a global raster of soil carbon and a feature collection of ecosystems. I would like to average the carbon in each ecosystem using ReduceRegions in Google Earth Engine, but I need to run this calculation in an equal area projection like EckertIV or Mollweide.

My code works  fine when I don't reproject the data, but the values are incorrect at a global scale. I have been trying to reproject both the raster data and transform the feature collection to Mollweide projection and then use Reduce Regions (as seen in the code below), but I continue to get a "User Memory Capacity Exceeded" error when exporting the results as a csv **which did not happen prior to reprojecting**.

```js
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

//Define the Mollweide Projection
var Proj_Mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);

//Reproject SOC Raster to Mollweide at 250m resolution
var SOC_1m_tCHa_Mollweide = SOC_1m_tCHa.reproject({
  crs: Proj_Mollweide,
  scale: 250
});

// Transform Biomes into Mollweide 
var transform_mollweide = function(a) {
  var transformed_mollweide = a.transform(Proj_Mollweide, 1);
  return transformed_mollweide;
};
var Biomes_Mollweide = Biomes.map(transform_mollweide);

//Define the reducers
var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.count(),
  sharedInputs: true
});

//Reduce the SOC data within each biome polygon
var SOC_by_Biome = SOC_1m_tCHa_Mollweide.reduceRegions({
  collection: Biomes_Mollweide,
  reducer: reducers
});
```

Here is the link to the code I have been working with: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3db50c3c74fe41428c62c3f7193e131f

Is there a way to complete this calculation with the reprojected data in Google Earth Engine?

Comment: Have you tried using the `crs` argument of `reduceRegions()` instead of reprojecting in a seperate step? Also, if you haven't yet read the documentation about projection yet, I really recommend you do so: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections

Comment: I have read through the documentation about projection, but didn't find anything that could clear up or explain the issue I have been having. 
I just tried using the crs in reduceRegions() but got an error: "Unable to transform edge . . . . to EPSG:4326", which is the same error I got when I attempted to reproject only the raster dataset without reprojecting the feature collection.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this in Mollweide.  In my experience, anytime someone wants to use an Equal Area projection, it's because they're hoping to count pixels to produce an area. That's completely unnecessary with Earth Engine (and the reprojection is going to decrease your accuracy).  See this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_forest_03?hl=en#calculating-pixel-areas

Comment: Also, the errors are almost certainly from the polygons covering the Antarctic region.  Those polygons are going to exceed the map limits in the non-repeating Mollweide projection (they fall off the edge).  If you exclude them, its more likely to work.